# Symmetry and disorder in PCB Layouts

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

Very vague and general question.

For PCB layouts, is it better to have symmetric layouts or to break the symmetry between components?

Very simple example, say I want to use a Pi filter in my layout; which of these two configurations is better? the symmetric one or the asymmetric? is it irrelevant? **The length of the traces is conserved.**

[image]

In other words in PCB layouts, **should I strive for symmetry and regular arrangements of components or should I introduce some disorder**?

Comment: Longer traces mean more parasitic inductance and more parasitic capacitance. Therefore, short traces (and leads) are better than longer ones, regardless of symmetry. If you have the freedom to move the components around, consider moving them closer.

Comment: In special cases symmetry is needed, like a differential pair. For circuits in general it doesn't matter, and I've not heard of the award most pleasing layout of a pcb (yet).

Comment: In my own layouts I find it pleasing to the eye if they "look pretty", which may include some symmetry where possible. But sacrificing "prettiness" for functionality always comes 1st of necessary.

Comment: This is an EMC or RF question: application is required. There is no amount of context not worth including; the amount shown here is uselessly basic. A basic question in turn: why is there space at all? Minimizing lead lengths is generally better.  Move the caps in to flank the inductor.

Comment: It also depends on impedances. It's best to have the shortest traces possible when you're on the high impedance side.